# New update on app doesn't change site logos

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

When scrolling right on a section with multiple site questions, the picture on the left does not update. [image]

Android 5.0.2, OnePlus One, Stackexchange just updated to 1.0.69

Comment: Bah, how did I not catch that?!? On it...

Comment: Thanks! I look forward to another update, it's awesome to be able to see all hot questions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fixed as of version 1.0.70, which will be going out to the Play Store sometime later today.